# Searching for an app to Send & Recieve recording audio in emergency situtations

Tags: applications, tasker, automation

I tried to complete this task, using *tasker* and *automate* but didn't sucess.

I didn't found a way to send the audio message, to the second android in realtime (like whatsapp, or pushbullet).

I want to make a task that record 5 seconds, and send it to another android.
I want it, for my wife, so he can send me emergency alert, if something happen, and she needs me.

The another android (my android), will play the file.
I want it to always work. If the receiver is in a middle of a call, it will hangup and play the sound fil
.
The question:

1. How to record 5 seconds?
2. How to send it?
3. How to play it on the receiver?

You dont need to give me full answer, any help, and ways to solve it will be appreciate.

If you also need it, or it intetesting you, please upvote :)

Thank's.

Comment: Some ready-to-use apps for this can be found in my app list: [Personal Protection (Emergency Alerts)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_person).

Comment: Shows us your attempts made in Tasker and Automate.

Comment: The action Media -> Record Audio can start recording. Use Task -> Wait to wait for 5 seconds, then use Media -> Record Audio Stop to stop recording. The next step has alternatives. Phone -> Compose MMS can send MMS to an Android so you can send the recording as an MMS to your partner (I've never sent an MMS so I don't know about charges it may incur on you and receiving party). In your partner's mobile, setup a profile as Event -> Phone -> Received Text -> MMS (and other specific details). Use the action under Phone to end call and play a sound to let your partner know about the issue.

Comment: ...this requires your partner to explicitly download the MMS (not bothered  to automate that). An another option is to run an FTP server somewhere, upload the file there, get the URL, send the URL as SMS, receive SMS, download media from URL, hangup the call if call is active and play the downloaded file. Sounds easy, right? You're better off with Izzy's advice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many many things.

In the end... I success using sending simple MMS message.

Then I create a task, that on receive MMS, it will emulate touch events, for play the file (I run the messageing app, and click on the last message to play it)

http://www.pocketables.com/2013/07/how-to-emulate-touch-input-using-tasker-and-root.html